# Rspec cannot detect method call in activerecord method chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have the following controller action:

```
def index
    @companies = Company.order(:name).includes(:team_members, :user)

    if params[:search].present?
      @companies = @companies.where('name ilike ?', "%#{params['search']}%")
    end
end
```

and respective rspec test:

```
before :each do
  allow(Company).to receive(:where)

  get :index, search: 'search_query'
end

it 'filters the companies by the search parameter' do
  expect(Company).to have_received(:where).with('name ilike "%search_query%"')
end
```

However rspec is not detecting that the "where" method is being called on the Company class. I am getting the following error:

```
1) CompaniesController GET #index when search parameter is given filters the companies by the search parameter
     Failure/Error: expect(Company).to have_received(:where).with('name ilike "%search_query%"')
       (Company(id: integer, name: string, description: text, season: string, iac_rating: float, funding_history: text, smart_scores: float, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, logo: string, website: string, summary: text, pitch_deck: string, executive_summary: string, unique_factor: text, revenue_burn_rate: text, growth: text, category: string, typical_check_size: string, raising_amount: string, committed_amount: string, hq_location: string, sector: string, num_full_time_founders: string, user_id: integer, display_order: integer) (class)).where("name ilike \"%search_query%\"")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("name ilike \"%search_query%\"")
           received: 0 times
```

What is the proper way to test this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's `@companies` and not `Company` what's receiving `:where`.
In your test code you have to show how the mocks descend from `Company` in the same way `@companies` descend from `Company` in the real code. This is necessary to have RSpec match `@companies` with its respective mock, `@companies_mock`.

```
  before :each do
    @companies_mock = double('Company')
    @intermediate_mock = double('Company')

    allow(Company).to receive(:order).and_return @intermediate_mock
    allow(@intermediate_mock).to receive(:includes).and_return @companies_mock

    allow(@companies_mock).to receive(:where)

    get :index, search: 'search_query'
  end

  it 'filters the companies by the search parameter' do
    expect(@companies_mock).to have_received(:where).with('name ilike ?', "%search_query%")
  end
```

Some time has passed since you asked.  Hopefully you'll find it useful.